# How to use querydsl aggregations in spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Querydsl supports [aggregation queries](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.2/reference/html/ch03s02.html), the question is how to use this feature from spring-data-jpa.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only "real" integration of Querydsl into Spring Data JPA is to use Querydsl predicates instead of Spring Data Specifications, which can be executed using the QueryDslPredicateExecutor.
But both only serve to formulate WHERE statements. I suggest this article:
https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl

But you can write Custom Repositories in Spring Data JPA, where any Querydsl feature can be used including aggregations:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: I appreciate your response.